# HTML in string with JavaScript code, JS not working

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my test javascript function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function test() {
        var sHTML = "<script type='text/javascript'> " +
                        "function showmsg() { " +
                            "alert('message'); " +
                        "} " +
                     "<\/script>" +
                     "<div>" +
                        "<a href='#' onclick='javascript:showmsg(); return false;'>click</a>" +
                     "</div>";
        var divTemp = document.createElement("div");
        divTemp.innerHTML = sHTML;

        var d = document.getElementById("div1");
        d.appendChild(divTemp);
    }
</script>
```

When I run this function, the `div` along with `a` tag is added in the `div1`, but when I click on anchor tag, it says `showmsg is not defined`, which is indicating that browser is NOT parsing the `script` tag.

How to achieve this without any 3rd party library?

**Update:**

The possible usage is, I want to allow user to create HTML templates along with JavaScript code, then my JS library will use those HTML templates to render user defined markup, plus allowing user to implement his/her custom logics through JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run `eval` on the script contents when using innerHTML. Try something like:

```
var scripts = divTemp.getElementsByTagName('script');
for(var i=0; i<scripts.length; i++) {
    eval(scripts[i].textContent);
}
```

Obviously, you need to do this in end, *after* injecting the innerHTML into the DOM.

Comment: @sallushan Yes it is: http://jsbin.com/huqaz/1/edit?html,js,output (I changed to `textContent` for FF support)

Comment: Yes, its working fine on jsbin, but when I ran it through my test web page in Chrome and IE, its NOT working. However if I run `eval()` in console, it creates the function.

Comment: OK got it working, actually it was the context issue, I used it as, `eval.call(window, scripts[i].textContent)`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Browsers do not run JavaScript code when a `<script>` tag is dynamically inserted like that.

Instead of that, you can just define the function directly!

```
    function test() {
      window.showmsg = function() {
        alert("message");
      };

      var sHTML = "<div>" +
                    "<a href='#' onclick='javascript:showmsg(); return false;'>click</a>" +
                 "</div>";
    var divTemp = document.createElement("div");
    divTemp.innerHTML = sHTML;

    var d = document.getElementById("div1");
    d.appendChild(divTemp);
}
```

Libraries like jQuery have code to strip `<script>` blocks out of text that's being stuffed into some element's `innerHTML`, and then evaluate it with `eval()`, so that's one thing to do if the code is somehow "stuck" in a block of content.

Comment: yes obviously, but the problem is I have this thing in string, so can't define the function

Comment: @sallushan well if you could provide more context it might be possible to offer specific suggestions. As I said in my answer, some DOM manipulation libraries provide this service. If you don't want to use such a library, you can just steal code from one.

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery, is this can help you :

```
$('<script>function test(){alert("message");};</' + 'script><div><a href="#" onclick="test();">click</a></div>').appendTo(document.body)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TSWsF/

Comment: thanks zeomega, trying to avoid any 3rd party library